How to have an application (running on port 7443) be accessible via IPtables on port 443 but not 7443?
I have a Python HTTP server on one machine with IP address - IP1 running at port 7443.
I would like to drop all the connections of INPUT by default from outside world except 443, 22 (7443 should be blocked)
I want all the connections to 443 to be redirected to 7443 internally.
Thing is from outside, if I query wget http://IP1:7443 it should not be accessible at all. But wget http://IP1:443 should connect to that server running 7443 in that machine.
But I couldn't access the server with the following rules:
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [3589:735248]
:INPUT ACCEPT [3526:729437]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [40:5729]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [40:5729]

# Redirect incoming traffic on port 443 to port 7443
-I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j LOG --log-prefix "PREROUTING-443: "
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:7443

COMMIT

*filter
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1115:183418]

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 

# Allow loopback traffic (local communication)
-I INPUT -p tcp -i lo -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUT-LO: "
-A INPUT -p tcp -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow incoming connections on port 443 (public-facing, for redirection)
-I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUT-443: "
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Allow incoming SSH connections on port 22 (SSH)
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT


-A INPUT -j DROP

COMMIT

Thing is if I added the line -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7443 -j ACCEPT it's working but the server is being accessible from 7443, which I don't want for 7443 but to be via 443
Note 1: I'm running the server on all interfaces -> 0.0.0.0:7443.
Note 2: I've tested the redirection by accepting 7443 and it worked and I don't have any firewall or ufw running.

The first thing I would do is to make sure the server listens only on 127.0.0.1. Is there a reason you can't do that?

The normal way to handle something like this is to run a web server (such as nginx) as reverse TLS proxy. The web server then listens on 443, handles TLS, does some first-in-line security stuff, and then hands off the request to the actual application. Preferably though a Unix Domain Socket instead of a network port, but either would work. Is there a reason you're not using such a setup?


# Allow incoming connections on port 443 (public-facing, for redirection)


Notice the chain names – you rewrite the packet in the "PREROUTING" chain (i.e. before routing), whereas "INPUT" rules are checked after routing (because routing is what decides between INPUT and FORWARD), and therefore redirects in "PREROUTING" happen before "INPUT".
This means that INPUT (or FORWARD) will only see packets having the new port number, so you must allow --dport 7443, not --dport 443.
If you needed for some reason to check the original (pre-rewrite) addresses or ports in your INPUT rules, you would have to use the -m conntrack module to pull that information from the NAT state table, e.g. --ctorigdstport 443 and perhaps also --ctstate DNAT.
The nftables equivalent is ct original proto-dst 443 and ct status dnat.

but the server is being accessible from 7443, which I don't want for 7443 but to be via 443

Use --ctstate DNAT (from the aforementioned -m conntrack module) to make sure only redirected connections are allowed.
You can combine it with either --dport 7443 or --ctorigdstport 443 (or both).

Fantastic... It works.. I can check pre-write ports and then add filter with ctorigdstport. For better security i'll add dport check as well. Thank you.
